# ¿Como visualizar código HTML en delphi?

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-2010

El día de hoy realicé una herramienta. Consta de un evento `GetFeatureInfo()` que devuelve código HTML. Debo mostrarlo en una ventana con el fin que el usuario visualice tal información.

¿Cómo puedo renderizar el código HTML de tal manera que Delphi interprete todo y se vea como en un navegador?

Comment: No manejo Delphi, pero tu pregunta se me hizo interesante +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el componente TWebBrowser para visualizar código HTML directamente en tu aplicación.

[image: HTML en un formulario]

Estoy asumiendo que tu HTML no viene de una URL, por lo que preparé un pequeño ejemplo, según se ve en la imagen, valiendome de la función `StuffHTML`, de la unidad `uStuffHTML`, que puedes encontrar en [Load HTML text into TWebBrowser control](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23992). Lo que hago es cargar el HTML ingresado el un TMemo en un TWebBrowser, con el siguiente código:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StuffHTML(WebBrowser1.ControlInterface, Memo1.Lines.Text);
end;
```

Comment: Me ayudo bastante esta información ya que no tenia ni idea de como manejar el WebBrowser, solo me falta saber porque mi petición GetFeatureInfo() me devuelve el código html incompleto, sin cerrar las etiquetas.

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda. Esa función la escribiste tu mismo?

Comment: No es parte de las herramienta de TATUK GIS

Comment: OK, suerte con eso entonces. Un saludo. :)